# Creating Class Rectangle

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and am trying to figure out how to do classes in rectangles. I have no idea where to start writing my code for this. Just looking for a little help on starting. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Create a class named 'Rectangle' with the following attributes and methods (sample run for each method included):

1. Each instance should have an x, y, width, and height attributes.
2. You should be able to pass the attributes when creating the rectangle as follows, (where x=5, y=10, width=50, height=100 in that order):

   r = Rectangle(5, 10, 50, 100)
3. Create a method that returns the rectangle as a string (hint: implement **str** ). For a rectangle object with attribute values x=5, y=10, width=50, height=100, it should return the string      “Rectangle(5, 10, 50, 100)”.

   r2 = Rectangle(5, 10, 50, 100)

   print(r2)

   Rectangle(5, 10, 50, 100)
4. Create a method called `right` that gets the value of the right edge of the rectangle. It should take no arguments:
   r3 = Rectangle(3, 5, 10, 20)

   r3.right()

   13

   r4 = Rectangle(12, 10, 72, 35)
   r4.right()
   84

5.Create a method called `bottom` that gets the value of the bottom edge of the rectangle.
 r5 = Rectangle(5, 7, 10, 6)

r5.bottom()

13
 r5.y += 12
 r5.bottom()

25
6. Create a method called `size` that returns the width and height of your rectangle.

r6 = Rectangle(1, 2, 3, 4)

r6.size()

(3, 4)

7.Create a method called `position` that returns the x and y coordinates of your rectangle.
 r6.position()

(1, 2)

8.Create a method called `area` that returns the area of your rectangle.

r6.area()

12

9.Create a method called `expand` that takes an offset value and returns a copy of the rectangle expanded with offset in all directions.

r = Rectangle(30, 40, 100, 110)

r
Rectangle(30, 40, 100, 110)

r1 = r.expand(offset=3)
r1
Rectangle(27, 37, 106, 116)

The original rectangle should not be modified.

r

Rectangle(30, 40, 100, 110)

Negative values should return a shrunken rectangle.

r.expand(-5)

Rectangle(35, 45, 90, 100)

```
class Rectangle:

  def __init__(self, X, Y, W, H):

     self.x = X

     self.y = Y

     self.w = W

     self.h = H

def complete(self):
    return self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h

def right(self):
    return self.x + self.w

def __str__(self):
    return('Rectangle(' + str(self.x) + ',' + str(self.y) + ','
                        + str(self.w) + ',' + str(self.h)+')')
def bottom(self):
    return self.y + self.h

def __str__(self):
    return('Rectangle(' + str(self.y) + ',' + str(self.h) + ','
                        + str(self.y) + ',' + str(self.h) + ')')
def size(self):
    return self.w,self.h

def position(self):
    return self.x,self.y

def area(self):
    return self.w * self.h

def expand(self):


print(Rectangle(5,10,50,100).complete())

print(Rectangle(3, 5, 10, 20).right())

print(Rectangle(12, 10, 72, 35).right())

print(Rectangle(5,7,10,6).bottom())

print(Rectangle(1,2,3,4).size())

print(Rectangle(1,2,3,4).position())

print(Rectangle(1,2,3,4).area())
```

Finally this is what I have came up with. I am lost as to how to start the last part #9. Also, If anyone sees any issues that I with my current code, help would be appreciated.

Comment: The class being called `Rectangle` shouldn't be a problem. Do you know how to create classes?

Comment: I think. I would do class Rectangle: ?

Comment: If I create the Class Rectangle, then I want to use def to set up all of the methods under the single class? So then I would end up with 8 def method telling the program to do what is listed above?

Comment: Yep, something like that.